# version code updated during commit

Tags: jenkins

I want to fetch the number from the below Jenkins console output and assign to the environment variable. Please can you able to help me

Herei is Jenkins output

```
17:01:38 :app:extractProguardFiles
17:01:38 :app:preReleaseBuild
17:01:38 :app:checkReleaseManifest
17:01:38 :app:increaseVersionCode
17:01:38 20:app:incrementVersionName
17:01:38 1.0.1.9:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
17:01:38 :usbaudiolib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
17:01:38 :usbaudiolib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
17:01:38 :usbaudiolib:checkReleaseManifest
17:01:38 :usbaudiolib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
17:01:38 
17:01:38 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I want to retrieve the 1.0.1.9 from the above console output (version number ) and assign the value to environment variable. Please can you able to help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? How does your code look? Are you using [tag:jenkins-pipeline] or freestyle jobs?

Comment: I am just trying get the value from the above output using power shell or batch command line but no luck. Yes Jenkins freestyle job.